# Tree-view plugin for bootstrap 5 + reactjs

Tags: javascript, html, css, react, bootstrap

Basically I'm searching for a plugin to use in react which at least relies on **bootstrap 5** for tree-views. Also, it has to be **free** and possibly open-source. I put bootstrap 5 as a requirement because I found online some minimal tree-view plugins for old versions, which don't fit my needs.

Also projects not depending on bootstrap are ok, as long as they:

- present themselves as aesthetically *modern* and are usable with a full bootstrap website without noting a major style difference
- provide full html + css + js code